# Flutter - Keyboard is raising on screen the FloatingActionButton

Tags: dart, flutter

I was using the `TextField` but the keyboard is raising the `FloatingActionButton`. I wonder if it is possible for the keyboard not to raise a `FloatingActionButton`?

In the code below I put two `FloatingActionButton` in two different ways but in both the keyboard goes up, which hinders the field filling since the FABs are in the same line as the `TextField`, according to the gif below.

Is there any way to solve this?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(      
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double _width = logicalSize.width;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA)),        
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Description",
                ),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
              new TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Description",
                ),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
              new TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Description",
                ),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Positioned(
            bottom: 16.0,
            left: (_width / 2) - 28,   
            child: new FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
              child: new Icon(Icons.check),
              onPressed: (){}
            ),            
          )
        ],        
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
        child: new Icon(Icons.check),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're designing a full screen dialog.

A floating action button represents the primary action in an application, like creating a new item. It is not what you'd use to confirm changes and dismiss a full screen dialog that contains a list of text fields.

Rather than using a `FloatingActionButton`, I would a recommend an `AppBar` with a `FlatButton` in the `actions` slot, like in this [Material design example](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-behavior):

[image: save]

You can see an example of how to build a full-screen dialog in Flutter in the [Gallery source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/full_screen_dialog_demo.dart).

Comment: Thanks, I understood the concept of Material Design, but in order to explore Flutter I realized that Stack and Positioned will always go up. To work around I rebuild the code with columns and it works only that when putting the SingleChildScrollView attribute of the Column mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, it stops working. So I opened another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982176/flutter-singlechildscrollview-interfering-in-columns