# Flutter - SingleChildScrollView interfering in columns

Tags: dart, flutter

I created a screen that works well with the columns, but I needed to scroll because of the keyboard.

When you insert the `SingleChildScrollView` or the `ListView` attribute the `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, it no longer works.

Was there any solution for that?

Gif without the `SingleChildScrollView` the screen does not roll and the `FloatingActionButton` is at the bottom of the screen

[image]

Gif with `SingleChildScrollView` the screen roll and he `FloatingActionButton` is not in bottom of the screen

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(      
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA)),        
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Description",
                      ),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                      ),
                    new TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Description",
                      ),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    ),
                    new TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Description",
                      ),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ),
              new Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                child: new FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.check),
                  onPressed: (){}
                ),                    
              )
            ],
        ),
      )            
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend against using `FloatingActionButton` in the way you are doing here. `FloatingActionButton` should be used for actions that always need to always be on screen at all times. See the [Material guidelines on button usage](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-usage) for suggestions on other button types that can be scrolled, like `RaisedButton` and `FlatButton`. You could use a `RaisedButton` here, but I think it would be better to make your screen a dialog and put the save action in the `AppBar` as I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971277/1463116) in your other question.

If you do decide to use a `RaisedButton` or `FlatButton`, keep in mind that scrollables don't normally change their item spacing based on the size of their container. Instead of using `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, you could put some `Padding` around your `RaisedButton` to separate it from the `TextField` elements. This will ensure that they are spaced the same distance apart regardless of rotation, screen size, and regardless of whether the keyboard is up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it helped a lot.

Comment: But why `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` doesn't work for children inside `Column`, when `Column` is inside `SingleChildScrollView`? Is there an alternative to achieve this?

Comment: @AnV After wrapping Column with SingleChildScrollView wrap it with Center widget.

Comment: @KamalPanara Do you mean like this `Center >> SCSV >> Column` or, `SCSV >> Center >> Column` ?

Comment: @shadow-recruit `Center >> SCSV >> Column`

Answer (score 4):

Follow the code below to register.

`MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` has been replaced with dynamic padding, depending on screen size.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(      
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double _height = logicalSize.height;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA)),        
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                height: 300.0,
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Description",
                      ),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    ),
                    new TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Description",
                      ),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    ),
                    new TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Description",
                      ),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ),
              new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: (_height - 450.0)),
                margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                child: new FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.check),
                  onPressed: (){}
                ),
              )
            ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Its worked for me. I have used Form with TextFormField().