# How to set an element to bottom of SingleCildScrollView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a screen that works well with the columns, but I needed to scroll because of the keyboard. I am using SingleChildScrollView, but Column's MainAxisAligment doesn't work inside of Scrollable.

**Main problem is - I need to set Widget at bottom of Scrollable**

I have googled this problem and found this:
[Flutter - SingleChildScrollView interfering in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982176/flutter-singlechildscrollview-interfering-in-columns)
But there are no solution for this concrete problem.

**My code:**

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildTextField(
                    'E-mail',
                    (text) {},
                    controller: _loginController,
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                    hintColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  ),
                  buildTextField(
                    'Password',
                    (text) {},
                    focus: _textSecondFocusNode,
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    onSubmit: (_) => presenter.login(_loginController.text, _passwordController.text),
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                    hintColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                    letterSpacing: 15,
                    icon: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                      },
                      child: Image.asset('assets/ic_eye.png'),
                    ),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 4, bottom: 4),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text(
                      'Registration',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor, decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                    ),
                    onTap: () =>
                        Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => StartRegistrationScreen())),
                  ),
                ),
                Buttons.buildRaisedButton(
                  Text(
                    'Login',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17, fontFamily: 'SFUIDisplay'),
                  ),
                  (){},
                  color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                  disabledColor: Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
                  child: Text(
                    'Forgot password',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89KsB.png) with scrollable content beacuse of keyboard.
But I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIWcZ.png)

Comment: @anmol.majhail  Between `Form` and `Column`?

Answer (score -1):

Wrap an expanded widget in your column widgets in your top section so that it will keep expanding until the bottom. Then after that, place your login button below it. The keyboard wont override your login button widget then.

Comment: This will make the bottom overflow when the keyboard appear